# How to add credentials in simple speech sample app (ATT speech API)

Tags: ios, speech

How do I go about adding credentials in **speechConfig.m**, a simple speech sample app ATT speech API?

```
/** Unobfuscates the OAuth client_id credential for the application. **/
NSString* SpeechOAuthKey(void)
{
    #error Add code to unobfuscate your Speech API credentials, then delete this line.
    return MY_UNOBFUSCATE(my_obfuscated_client_id);
}

/** Unobfuscates the OAuth client_secret credential for the application. **/
NSString* SpeechOAuthSecret(void)
{
    #error Add code to unobfuscate your Speech API credentials, then delete this line.
    return MY_UNOBFUSCATE(my_obfuscated_client_secret);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to run the code with un-obfuscated credentials (not secure), just comment out the '#error' lines and return the string which is your portal app key and secret.

When you're ready for a production app you should investigate your favorite security routine to un-obfuscate the key and secret which will be stored in your app and wrap it up in method which returns the un-obfuscated plain text key/secret from the obfuscated key/secret that ships with your code.

If you still need more assistance, please log a ticket at the developer.att.com portal under 'support->log a ticket'.